# Snow Leopard Python 2.6 problems getting PIL to work

Tags: python, image-manipulation, osx-snow-leopard, pylons, python-imaging-library

I installed libjpeg and PIL, but when I try to save a JPG image, I always get this error:

**ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed**

Any help much appreciated!

I tried to import _imaging w/ Python interpreter to see what's wrong and got this:

```
    >>> import _imaging
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just hit this as well on SL, and the problem is likely your libjpeg was built without a matching architecture.  Assuming you're using MacPorts, run `file /opt/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib`.  The right way is to build everything with MacPorts as `+universal`, see 
[Universal Binaries in MacPorts](http://rcaguilar.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/universal-binaries-in-macports/) as it relates to PIL dependencies.

Comment: thanks, I think you are right, i will check it out and verify

Answer (score 4):

A lot of these errors happen when compiling from source when you've previously installed python tools from fink or ports. For example the `_jpeg_resync_to_restart` error can happen when you've got leftover libjpeg files in `/opt/local/lib`. Try this:

```
cd /opt/local/lib
sudo rm *jpeg*
```

Then recompile libjpeg (starting with `make clean`), then recompile PIL (starting with `rm -Rf build`).

After that, `import _imaging` should work. Did for me anyway.

Comment: This worked for me, however, I also had conflicts from the fink package installer, which installs files in /sw. I also found the following answer to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404956/installing-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Thanks for the added error message. This is apparently a problem with the jpeglib on Snow Leopard. Have you tried this?

http://jetfar.com/libjpeg-and-python-imaging-pil-on-snow-leopard/

Comment: I followed this link to the dot and I still get this error :( - it seems whatever I try I can't get this to work, tried several sources on google already.

Comment: I've also installed libjpeg7, libjpeg6 (I have not uninstalled any version - maybe this is why?).

Comment: How did you install these libraries and to what location? Chances are that location is not in the dynamic load search path. Try running otool -L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so

Comment: @resopollution: OK, I don't have Snow Leopard, so I'm no more help now. :)

Comment: Perhaps you have to reinstall PIL after having installed libjpeg. I'm running python and PIL on snow leopard without any problems. I installed libjpeg7 first for something else (libgd I think).

Comment: Oh, absolutely, you need to recompile it even, so you must remove the build directory under the PIL source and do a reinstall. The build process will not notice that the library has been updated, AFAIK.

Comment: Tried everything , still no go :(

Comment: same error everytime about "Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart" seems other people have the problem, but no solution

Answer (score 1):

I kept having this problem as well. It turned out to be related to a change I made to my .bash_profile (forcing the usage of ggc-4.0) when trying to fix a MySQLdb installation problem.

http://www.brambraakman.com/blog/comments/installing_pil_in_snow_leopard_jpeg_resync_to_restart_error/