# Installing PIL with JPEG support on Mac OS X

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

I posted a question before regarding this subject, and read other ones posted before, but none has successfully solved my problem.

I am trying to install PIL on Mac OS X Lion, as I need it for a Django application. I also need JPEG support, so I need a JPEG decoder as well.

I have tried to download the libjpeg sources and compile them, and install PIL, but it doesn't recognize the directory.

So what I would like, and I believe this exists somewhere, is a method to install both PIL and libjpeg with a package installer, without the need for any compilation whatsoever!

Thank you in advance for every reply.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I installed libjpeg and PIL on Snow and it was migrated without problems to Lion.

I think however that you have the same problem I faced with installing libjpeg 7 on Snow. The solution for me was :

> - Make sure that you are NOT using GCC 4.0. That means those export lines in your .bash_profile file that you needed to get MySQLdb
>     working now need to go away.
> - get (http://www.ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v7.tar.gz) and do the usual ./configure && make && make install (or whatever the readme says).
> - Before installing PIL but after installing libjpeg, change the “JPEG_ROOT = None” line in my setup.py file to “JPEG_ROOT =
>     libinclude(“/usr/local”)”

I got this from a comment on [this blog](http://jetfar.com/libjpeg-and-python-imaging-pil-on-snow-leopard/).

Afterwards you can reinstall PIL through pip or easy_install. Make sure all the compiled stuff from your last run is deleted (sometimes you need to do this manually). I used virtualenv and pip.

Comment: Amazing. That was it. I guess my previous try was just lack of the correct parameters when installing libjpeg or PIL. This was a lifesaver. Thank you !

Comment: here is a nice description on how to install under a virtualenv: http://devdetails.com/2011/09/20/install-pil-in-a-virtualenv-on-mac-osx-lion/

Answer (score 93):

In our virtualenv we found all we needed to do was:

```
pip uninstall PIL
brew install libjpeg
pip install PIL
```

which is simpler than some of the above and may be enough for others with this problem too.
Although there was an xcode warning on the brew and a setup.py package warning on the reinstall of PIL, all the tests that previously failed with jpeg decode errors successfully ran after just the quick action above.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you have homebrew and pip, and then run:

```
brew install libjpeg
pip install pil
```

Answer (score 11):

I used the following binary to get libpng and libjpeg installed systemwide on OSX:

[libpng & libjpeg for OSX](http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html)

Because I already had PIL installed (via pip on a virtualenv), I ran:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip install PIL --upgrade
```

This resolved the `decoder JPEG not available` error for me.

**UPDATE:**

If encountering the error `encoder jpeg not available`, you may need to install `libjpeg`. If using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install libjpeg
```

Comment: not solving on Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4 IOError: encoder jpeg not available

Comment: I installed libjpeg before

Comment: These work for me: brew install libjpeg, pip uninstall PIL, pip uninstall pillow, pip install pillow

Comment: This worked for me on Mavericks 10.9: binary, then pip uninstall/reinstall. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for Mac OSX 10.7.5

Comment: Remember to add the `--no-cache-dir` option to pip then it should work as you reinstall either Pillow or PIL.

Answer (score 3):

Worth noting and good information to have whenever working with Python and PIL: If you use virtualenv (and I think it's a very good idea), PIL may not correctly detect the image libraries on your system and install without JPEG/PNG support.  Use the pillow package for a compatible PIL fork that finds them correctly.

Comment: This worked for me when all of the other solutions failed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For OSX, pip install PIL had:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      darwin 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
              [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
*** JPEG support not available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588936/cant-get-python-imaging-library-to-find-jpeg-support#_=_) led to something that works.

Install the libraries from [here](http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you have macports installed, you should do a:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port install py27-pil
```

It's easier than the easy_install + libjpeg method since macports install the right dependencies.

Comment: I have macports installed on lion, I can see many py27-* but cannot see py27-pil, any ideas? Thanks