# Can't get Python Imaging Library to find JPEG support

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, libjpeg

This is on Mountain Lion (OSX 10.8.3).  So I downloaded, built, and installed the assorted required libraries.  I modified setup.py to refer to the right places...

```
TCL_ROOT = libinclude("/usr")
JPEG_ROOT = libinclude("/usr/local")
ZLIB_ROOT = libinclude("/usr")
FREETYPE_ROOT = libinclude("/usr/local")
LCMS_ROOT = libinclude("/usr/local")
```

And running setup.py seems to work...

```
airguitar:Imaging-1.1.7 chuck 597$ python setup.py build_ext -i
running build_ext
--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version       1.1.7
platform      darwin 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
              [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
--- LITTLECMS support available
--------------------------------------------------------------------
To check the build, run the selftest.py script.
```

After this I successfully ran `sudo python setup.py install`.  But when I run the self test I get...

```
airguitar:Imaging-1.1.7 chuck 600$ python selftest.py 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL 1.1.7 TEST SUMMARY 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from ./PIL
Binary modules loaded from ./PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok
--- TKINTER support ok
*** JPEG support not installed
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
--- FREETYPE2 support ok
--- LITTLECMS support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Running selftest:
*****************************************************************
Failure in example:
try:
 _info(Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT, "Images/lena.jpg")))
except IOError, v:
 print v
from line #24 of selftest.testimage
Expected: ('JPEG', 'RGB', (128, 128))
Got: decoder jpeg not available
1 items had failures:
   1 of  57 in selftest.testimage
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
*** 1 tests of 57 failed.
```

Note that the self test claims that I don't have JPEG support installed.

Suggestions?

**Update: It gets worse...**

I suspected that perhaps the problem was that before I knew I had to build my own JPEG and other libraries, I had run the setup.  So I tried to start over with a clean PIL distribution.  Now when I run `python setup.py build` I eventually get...

```
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c libImaging/JpegDecode.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/libImaging/JpegDecode.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
libImaging/JpegDecode.c:118:1: error: conflicting types for 'ImagingJpegDecode'
ImagingJpegDecode(Imaging im, ImagingCodecState state, UINT8* buf, int bytes)
^
libImaging/Imaging.h:415:12: note: previous declaration is here
extern int ImagingJpegDecode(Imaging im, ImagingCodecState state,
           ^
libImaging/JpegDecode.c:145:41: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to
      'const JOCTET *' (aka 'const char *') from 'UINT8 *' (aka 'short *')
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    context->source.pub.next_input_byte = buf;
                                        ^ ~~~
libImaging/JpegDecode.c:151:49: error: 'const JOCTET *' (aka 'const char *') and
      'UINT8 *' (aka 'short *') are not pointers to compatible types
            return context->source.pub.next_input_byte - buf; 
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~
libImaging/JpegDecode.c:235:21: warning: incompatible pointer types passing
      'UINT8 *' (aka 'short *') to parameter of type 'unsigned char *'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
            state->shuffle((UINT8*) im->image[state->y + state->yoff] +
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libImaging/JpegDecode.c:262:48: error: 'const JOCTET *' (aka 'const char *') and
      'UINT8 *' (aka 'short *') are not pointers to compatible types
    return context->source.pub.next_input_byte - buf; 
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~
2 warnings and 3 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I have no idea how to configure this to do the 'right thing'.  Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install from here- http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html

Reinstall PIL

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  But first I had to run python setup.py clean.  Someday when I have time I will dig into the details.  For now, I'm thrilled that it all works.  Thanks, again.