# scipy.misc.imread returns object with no size/shape

Tags: python, scipy, python-imaging-library

I have a question that is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612293/scipy-misc-imread-creates-an-image-with-no-size-or-shape), though not identical. My goal is to read a TIFF image using `scipy.misc.imread` and then use the array of grayscale values that is returned by the function. When I do this for one images of dimensions 1280x960 px, I get what I need. However, when I attempt the same for a larger image (6272x897 px), `imread` returns the following object:

```
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=LA size=6272x897 at 0x3906B48>
```

I would like to extract the data out of this object, for instance using `.getdata()`, but the object itself does not seem to have any shape or size, as was the case in the question I linked above. Ben then proposed the following solution:

```
pip uninstall PIL
brew install libjpeg
pip install PIL
```

However, I'm working with a TIFF file, rather than JPEG (`libtiff` appears to be installed). Also, reading a smaller image works fine, whereas reading a big one suddenly causes problems. Does anyone have any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Which Scipy version are you using? From [the source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/misc/pilutil.py#L174), it is supposed to return an array. Does your PIL object have a `__array__` method?

Comment: `scipy.__version__` returns 0.12.0, `img.__array__` returns `<built-in method __array__ of numpy.ndarray object at 0x2e9c4a0>`

Comment: And what happens if you load it with `im = Image.open(name)`? Does that have the `__array__` method?

Comment: No, with `im = Image.open(name)` it does not have the `__array__` method (AttributeError is raised)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scipy is calling `np.array`, but when it fails to see `__array__`, creates an object array instead. You should use raw PIL and read the information from there, there are many questions in SO on how to convert a PIL object into a Numpy array.

The reason why it works with smaller ones may be that the size is so big that it makes PIL be careful about memory, but I am not sure.

An alternative that may work would be to use Pillow (a fork of PIL), or [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html)

Comment: Trying to convert the PIL object to Numpy didn't quite work for me, but using matplotlib surely did the trick.