# Google Cloud ML scipy.misc.imread returning <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile>

Tags: scipy, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am running the following snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.misc
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io

file = file_io.FileIO('gs://BUCKET/data/celebA/000007.jpg', mode='r')
img = scipy.misc.imread(file)
```

If I run that snippet in Cloud Console, I get back a proper array. But when that same snippet runs in Cloud ML, the img object is

`<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=178x218 at 0x7F1F8F26DA10>`

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612293/scipy-misc-imread-creates-an-image-with-no-size-or-shape) suggests that libjpeg was not installed when PIL was installed. The [Cloud ML Runtime Version list](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/runtime-version-list) shows that for Tensorflow 0.12, libjpeg-dev is an installed debian package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue on Cloud ML, and it seems to be an issue with the version of file_io in Tensorflow 0.12.1, and goes away if Tensorflow 1.0 is installed.

If you can, upgrade to the 1.0 build of TF.

If you need a 0.12 version, the Cloud ML "0.12" runtime uses the official 0.12.1 build of TF, but you can upload your own version to install if you like.  I did not track down exactly when the issue was fixed but a [Nightly](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/) Tensorflow build from Feb 2nd seemed to work.