# decoder jpeg not available mac osx

Tags: python-imaging-library, django-1.7

I am getting a decoder jpeg not available. I libjpeg installed using brew but when I install pillow, is get *** JPEG support not available

I had this working and all of a sudden it stopped working. I have unlinked and linked libjpeg again like it was suggested in few other SO answers. I have also uninstalled pillow and libjpeg and then installed it again, no joy.

Comment: Are you using a Python virtual environment?

Answer (score 7):

Have you installed `libjpeg-dev`?

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev`

Edit: realized you're probably on OSX. Have you tried the following step from the accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404956/installing-pil-with-jpeg-support-on-mac-os-x)?

- Before installing PIL but after installing libjpeg, change the “JPEG_ROOT = None” line in my setup.py file to “JPEG_ROOT = libinclude(“/usr/local”)” (or wherever libjpeg is installed)

Have you tried the most common solution to this problem?

```
$ pip uninstall pillow`
$ brew install libjpeg`
$ pip install pillow`
```

Comment: I am not using PIL, installing Pillow and did the steps you mentioned already.

Comment: I've updated my answer for pillow. Are you using a Python virtual environment such as virtualenv?

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot to mention that. Weirdly this was working, just stopped after 2 months.Yeah did that with Pillow only.

Comment: It may be either a permissions issue or a path issue. Have you moved anything around? Is everything you need on your path? Maybe reset the permissions of your VM and the libjpeg files.

Comment: No I haven't changed anything, I installed libjpeg using brew, thought it might be symlinks issues so unlinked and linked back again. Completely re-installed virtual env and still no good.

Comment: DO remember to use the `--no-cache-dir` option when reinstalling `Pillow`.

Answer (score 2):

I installed libjpeg form http://ethan.tira-thompson.com/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html and it works now. Probably brew didn't create symlinks where its being expected.